# The column set to not null is allowing blank rows ( ' ' )

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want the row to be as NULL even if the value given during insert is ('','')
But now when I insert like this, it inserts a blank row in not null column. 
I tried to alter the table but it doesnt work.

```
alter table Organization add check (org_name != '')
```

I expect output to reject the entry when I try to insert blank value in not null column.

Comment: It doesn't work how? [It works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10b9fea39a23b375d44f8ef6071a77c2) unless you have something you don't tell us about it.

Comment: @Sami This is an answer in itself. You are absolutely right.

Comment: @svisvesh You might want to try to use NULLIFF (org_name, '') during the insert as a workaround.

Comment: Maybe you need to add some `trim` function? `LTRIM(org_name) != ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami pointed out, the real issue may be something different then what you suspect. As a workaround, you can make use of the NULLIF function, like this:

```
USE TEMPDB
CREATE TABLE #Org (ID INT, org_name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #Source (ColA INT, ColB VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO #Source VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, '')

INSERT INTO #Org
SELECT ColA,
      NULLIF (ColB, '')
FROM #Source

DROP TABLE #Org, #Source

-- Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
-- Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'org_name', table 'tempdb.dbo.#Org________________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000002F34'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
-- The statement has been terminated.
```